# PLL phase error plot confusion

Tags: three-phase, matlab, pll

I am working on the implementation of different PLL for grid-connected converters. I have confusion in a particular plot for my research which is the phase error.

First of all, I generated the reference phase signal by integrating a constant nominal frequency and then inserting a modulus at the value 2pi. When I plot the estimated phase angle and the reference I get the upper plot (see attached)

The second thing is when I try to calculate the error in the phase estimation. I get the down plot, with these spikes that are not periodic. They happen because sometimes, the reference value is slightly less than the estimated value causing these spikes. See the second picture attached.

My question is what am I doing wrong here? Or there is nothing wrong and should I ignore these errors. Especially that the steady state error of the frequency is nearly 1e-3.

[image: estimated vs reference (top), error (bottom)]

[image: zoomed in version]

Answer (score 0):

Phase maps to a segment of the real number line that's \$2\pi\$ radians long.  It looks like your choice of math packages is mapping that in the segment \$\theta \in \left [ 0,\ 2\pi \right )\$.

At the very least, you want to map the phase to the segment \$\theta \in [-\pi, +\pi)\$.  If you start controlling the phase with a PLL that has a type 1 loop filter (i.e.: it has an integrator) then your phase error will spend as much time slightly negative as it will spend slightly positive -- if you use \$\theta \in \left [ 0,\ 2\pi \right )\$, then the phase error will be constantly jumping from near 0 to near \$2\pi\$, and your loop *will not work*.